# Grouping data based on a value in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am trying to create new id based on logon page name. Whenever logon page_name is encountered, it will be considered as one session until it finds next logon page name. The new id will be generated based on session count for that id.

**Sample data set:**

| id | page_name | visited_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:04:40.000 |
| ABC-123 | smscode | 2023-02-23 04:20:40.000 |
| ABC-123 | acct balance | 2023-02-23 04:21:40.000 |
| ABC-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:54:40.000 |
| ABC-123 | transfer | 2023-02-23 04:54:40.000 |
| CDE-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:58:40.000 |

**SQL used:**

```
with session_cnt
as
(
select id, page_name, visited_time, 
row_number() over (partition by id, page_name order by visited_time asc) as session_count, 
visited_time
from table
)
select id, page_name, visited_time, session_count, array_join(array_agg(session_count), '-', 'null)) as new_id
from session_cnt
```

Above SQL seems to return new id based on other page names too. I would like to group the session count based on id and page_name=logon.

**Expected result:**

| id | page_name | visited_time | session_count | new_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:04:40.000 | 1 | ABC-123-1 |
| ABC-123 | smscode | 2023-02-23 04:20:40.000 | 1 | ABC-123-1 |
| ABC-123 | acct balance | 2023-02-23 04:21:40.000 | 1 | ABC-123-1 |
| ABC-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:54:40.000 | 2 | ABC-123-2 |
| ABC-123 | transfer | 2023-02-23 04:54:40.000 | 2 | ABC-123-2 |
| CDE-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:58:40.000 | 1 | CDE-123-1 |

Please advise how I can achieve this in Athena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cumulative sum (using [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html)) over `page_name` equal to `'logon'`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (id, page_name, visited_time) as (
    values ('ABC-123',  'logon',    '2023-02-23 04:04:40.000'),
    ('ABC-123', 'smscode',  '2023-02-23 04:20:40.000'),
    ('ABC-123', 'acct balance', '2023-02-23 04:21:40.000'),
    ('ABC-123', 'logon',    '2023-02-23 04:54:40.000'),
    ('ABC-123', 'transfer', '2023-02-23 04:54:40.000'),
    ('CDE-123', 'logon',    '2023-02-23 04:58:40.000')
)

-- query
select *,
  sum(if(page_name = 'logon', 1)) over(partition by id order by visited_time) 
      as session_id 
from dataset;
```

Output:

| id | page_name | visited_time | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CDE-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:58:40.000 | 1 |
| ABC-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:04:40.000 | 1 |
| ABC-123 | smscode | 2023-02-23 04:20:40.000 | 1 |
| ABC-123 | acct balance | 2023-02-23 04:21:40.000 | 1 |
| ABC-123 | logon | 2023-02-23 04:54:40.000 | 2 |
| ABC-123 | transfer | 2023-02-23 04:54:40.000 | 2 |

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this. How can I concatenate ID and session id in Athena?

Comment: Also, Athena doesn't support If keyword

Comment: @vvazza i don't know what you are doing wrong, but Athena supports `if`. But you can substitute it with `case`

Comment: Yes, I used case and it worked. ```sum(case when page_name='logon' then 1 end) over (partition by id order by visited_time) as session_count```

Comment: Could you tell me how I can concatenate ID and session_count in Athena?

Comment: @vvazza `id || (cast session_id as varchar)`, see the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html)

Comment: Wonderful. I am still trying to understand how the sum function we added worked here. We are partition it based on id, and then summing up based on page_name=logon. Would you be kind to explain how sum function worked there?

Comment: @vvazza added link to window functions description. Basically it performs cumulative sum over the expression from all the previous rows up to current one (using ordering by the timestamp column).

Comment: Thank you. The link doesn't seem to work. Could you please check? Thanks, once again for your help

Comment: @vvazza what exactly? Can you please show sample data and query which results in wrong output?

Comment: No. The query worked fine. The link for window functions you shared doesn't seem to work

Comment: @vvazza fixed now.